¿Por qué votar negativo en vez de corregir a un nuevo usuario que responde?
venía con esta consulta, debido a que el usuario Deivintir, aportó una respuesta/solución a un problema de un usuario. En dicha pregunta, di una respuesta diferente y "más completa" al problema del OP.
Dicha publicación es la siguiente: Como puedo hacer para que mi app permita cobrar con decimal?
Esto va al punto de que poder comentar en las publicaciones de otros, es un privilegio alcanzado a los 50 puntos, lo cuál limíta a un nuevo usuario bastante en cuanto a comentar algo de manera correcta, y por ende solo puede responder de manera incompleta.

Por lo que el cambio sugerido es, no votar y motivar al nuevo usuario a responder de una manera más completa, de este modo invitarle y darle una bienvenida a la comunidad, y a StackOverflow como tal.

Sinceramente acabo de publicar esta duda, y me topo con otro resultado similar. No hay aporte, link a [how-to-answer], nada que ayude al nuevo a entender como responder en el sitio :> https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/623906/131662

en el segundo caso, no lo hay, porque ese usuario respondio 7 preguntas en un lapso de menos de un dia.. todas con una calidad de respuesta dudosa.. y ya le deje los enlances correspondientes en otra respuesta...

Si, ese lo estabamos discutiendo en el chat

"Cualquier respuesta que encamine a los lectores en la dirección correcta ayudará siempre y cuando menciones limitaciones, supuestos, o simplificaciones en tu respuesta. La brevedad es aceptable pero respuestas robustas son las mejores." --> https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer
